# What is accomplished by standing dumbbell lat raises that isn’t accomplished by starting Arnold presses?

Tags: shoulders, dumbbells, anatomy

I’ve been told before that Arnold presses work the entire shoulder and that lateral raises specifically target the lateral deltoids. Does that mean that Arnold presses target everything that lat raises do and more?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is accomplished by standing dumbbell lat raises that isn’t accomplished by starting Arnold presses?

### Targeted hypertrophy

Some times when you're doing an exercise that targets multiple muscles, ONE of those muscle groups will start to get exhausted, while others still have more to give. For that reason, we maintain a repertoire of isolation exercises.

In this case, let's say you're doing Arnolds, and your triceps are starting to fail you on the lockout, but your lateral deltoids still aren't even pumped. Lat raises to the rescue!

There are countless examples of this:

- glutes giving out on deadlifts, but quads are still good for more? Leg extensions!
- triceps giving out on bench, but your pecs aren't close to done? Cable/dumbbell fly!
- lateral deltoids giving out on Arnolds, but front deltoids barely feeling it? Front raises!

### Targeted size adjustments

Bodybuilders do a LOT of isolation work, and not only for the reason above. The other reason is when they notice a muscle group that isn't developed as clearly as they would like, or it's lagging behind other muscle groups, creating visual imbalances that they don't like.

You don't *have to* be a bodybuilder to feel that way. We all notice our own shortcomings (real or imagined) in the mirror, and that's another reason to know how to target them without interference or assistance from other muscle groups.